# What is the best way to emulate keyboard shortcuts with touchpad gestures?

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

On my Lenovo 0410 I am using an Ubuntu derivative called Elementary OS. You can press Super+W to show your current windows like on most other Ubuntu derivatives. I would like to use this feature with a specific touchpad gesture, e.g. three finger swipe to the top. Is that possible? And if it is, what is the most resource efficient and most reliable way to do it?

Comment: Global keyboard shortcuts are part of your DE (desktop environment), although they may be configured to some default by the distro.  So you want to find out how to do this for a particular DE (GNOME, KDE, etc) rather than "for ubuntu".  There may also be third party software that will map gestures to spoof keyboard events, in which case neither the distro nor the DE matters.

Comment: Are you using a thinkpad 410? This touchpad is not multi-touch.

Comment: No, ideapad u410. It has a multi-touch touchpad with gestures that work on elementary, e.g. 2 finger scrolling.